# How to change UIBezierPath strokeColor without redrawing it

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath

I have created a body image map using beziercurves.

In my customView, I have created around 62 bezierpaths for each body part! Initially all these are set to a default color.And when User touch any of these paths, I am trying to change their stroke color.

[image]

One way is to declare a bool variable for every bezierPath, and toggle them accordingly.But I think this is hard way to achieve it. Declaring 62 additional bool vars and managing them.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Declare the bezier properties:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath * rightEyePath;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath * leftEyePath;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath * nosePath;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBezierPath * mouthPath;
.... so on
```

and drawing them in drawRect:

```
 _leftEyePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[_leftEyePath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(...)];
[_leftEyePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(...))];
[_leftEyePath closePath];
[_defaultColor setStroke];
_leftEyePath.lineWidth = 0.5;
[_leftEyePath stroke];
```

and in the touchesMove method, I am trying to change the bezier strokeColor:

```
if ([_rightEyePath containsPoint:touchPoint])
{
    [_defaultColor setStroke];
    _rightEyePath.lineWidth = 0.5;
    [_rightEyePath stroke];
}
```

It didn't work , as I didn't call setNeedsDisplay which redraw the bezier .

how can I pass a different color in drawRect for these 62 beziers without having 62 bool vars declared.

I am looking for the efficient way to achieve the task.

Comment: why have you done everything as separate, unique variables, rather than as an array / list / collection?  You could have your 62 constants defining the body parts in an enumerator, and store the bezier, current state, colour and whatever else you need stored together...

Comment: if I use arrays, then I need to memorize all their indexes again! And I need to draw each bezier differently, i think enumerator doesnt work in this case! @Russell

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking for objective-C, but here's a pseudo-code swift example of what I mean

set up the enumerators that you need

```
enum BodyPartEnumerator : Int {
    case _rightEyePath = 0
    case _leftEyePath = 1
    // and all the rest...
}
```

then define the data structure you need

```
struct BodyPartData {
    var bodyPartIndex : Int
    var bezierPath : UIBezierPath
    var selected : Bool
}
```

define an array for the body parts

```
var bodyPartData : [BodyPartData] = []
```

then - either hard-code each body part (as you are doing currently), or (better) load the points in from a data file.  You could just store the vertices indexed by the body part enumerator

And then, in your touch method, something like this

```
for (index, bodyPart) in bodyPartData.enumerated()
{
    if bodyPart.bezierPath.contains(touchPoint)
    {
        bodyPartData[index].selected = true // probably need to clear any previous selections
        // redraw display
    }
}
```